# Deleting committed test folders / files on Google Code?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is there a way to remove the test folders and files that I have committed to a Google Code branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
svn delete your_file
```

to delete the file, and, then, use

```
svn commit
```

to push the deletion to the server -- but note that will not delete anything from the SVN history : the way SVN works is to keep a trace of everything, which means permanently deleting something is not "*allowed*".

If you want to completly remove a file from the repository's history, it's a lot harder, and will require you to be admin of the repository -- which you are not, on google code.

See this entry of the Subversion's FAQ, about that : [How do I completely remove a file from the repository's history?](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal)

Comment: but where will I type that "svn delete my_file" command ? , all i know is right click a folder or file and commit or branch/tag using the tortoise software lol

Comment: Oh, you are using a graphical tool, and not command-line ;; well, there should be some "delete" action in the right-click menu of TortoiseSVN, that will just run the `svn delete` command *(I don't have TortoiseSVN on my current computer, but the "delete" action should definitly be somewhere in that menu)*

Comment: daemn, im a windows user, and am reading this online manual about svn, is this svn command line stuff is out of the box ready with linux ?

Comment: Well, it's just that, on Linux, it's "more natural" and "not strange" to use the command-line interface, while, on windows, it's seen as kinda pre-historical ^^ ;; But graphical clients *(like TortoiseSVN)* only provide a GUI on top of the standard SVN commands ;; so, you should find a equivalent, using a GUI, for most standard SVN commands ;; and, if you're curious, you can still install the command-line client on windows ;-) ;; actually, it's pretty usefull when you want to automate some SVN manipulations *(just put a couple of svn commands in a .bat file, and voila)*

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to do:

```
svn delete blah
svn commit
```

provided everything is set up.

Comment: Of course that will not completely obliterate *blah*. You can still retrieve it by checking out an earlier version.