# How can I delete a folder under Google Code SVN?

Tags: svn, google-code

[image]

example:I want delete friendsmap.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting committed test folders / files on Google Code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189597/deleting-committed-test-folders-files-on-google-code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use svn to checkout the entire source tree, then `svn rm` to remove the directory from the working set, then commit.

Better yet, you can use `svn rm URL -m "Deleting that folder 'friendsmap' I don't like"` and provide the url of that folder, if you want to do it quicker. (from svn rm help: "Each item specified by a URL is deleted from the repository via an immediate commit.")

Answer (score 3):

Use TortoiseSVN repo-browser and from there delete the folder you want. If you already have TortoiseSVN it should be faster.

Comment: A perfectly good suggestion if the OP is on a platform for which TortoiseSVN is available.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the folder locally with `svn delete` and commit.

Comment: That's what usually I do. I make a commit after making all kind of changes required for a revision.